# Not able to add a custom command

Tags: webdriver-io

I want to create a custom command in a typescript webdriverIO project. But no matter what I do, the command always ends up with the error :

> TypeError: browser.waitAndClick is not a function.

Basically I wanted to add the same function they mentioned in webdriverIO doc. I am adding it from beforeAll() in my specs.

```
import { DEFAULT_TIMEOUT } from "../constants";
class CustomCommand {
    private static alreadyAdded = false;
    static addCommands(){
        if(!this.alreadyAdded) {
            browser.addCommand('waitAndClick', (el: WebdriverIO.Element) => {
                el.waitForDisplayed({timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT});
                el.click();
            }, true);

            browser.addCommand('waitAndSetValue', (el: WebdriverIO.Element, text: string) => {
                el.waitForDisplayed({timeout: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT});
                el.setValue(text);
            }, true);

            this.alreadyAdded = true;
        }
    }
}

export default CustomCommand;
```

And I am calling this addCommands() function from beforeAll() of a spec. But no luck!

Answer (score 2):

One nice person from slack channel helped me to find out the exact reason. Actually I overlooked something in doc : `If you register a custom command to the browser scope, the command won’t be accessible for elements. Likewise, if you register a command to the element scope, it won’t be accessible in the browser scope`. Turned out this is the reason. It is resolved now.

Passing `false` as third parameter in `addCommand()` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack-overflow!

Please note that there is no 'beforeAll' hook in webdriverio as per the docs [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#hooks).
It should work if you call this in before hook.

Answer (score 0):

based on the webdriverio docs: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/addCommand/

**Note**: don't forget to wrap inside before hook as ex bellow:

```
before: async function (capabilities, specs) {

        browser.addCommand('waitAndClick', async function (selector) {
            try {
                await $(selector).waitForExist();
                await $(selector).click();
            } catch (error) {
                throw new Error(`Could not click on selector: ${selector}`);
            }
        });


    },
```